# Can a signed Jar be run as an executable?

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

I ask because I have an unsigned jar that runs and a signed version that doesn't. Looking at the manifests, I see no main class thing for the signed one.

Do I have to run a signed jar from web start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, but if you don't have a Main-class: in the manifest, you can't run it as an executable.  If you know the main class, you can run it using the java executable, eg

```
$ java -classpath ./myjar.jar MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you build process is updated the manifast.mf

Answer (score -1):

you need to sign your jar to run outside of the web start sandbox......

[google here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jnlp+all-permissions&btnG=Search)