# Java Code Signing and WebStart

Tags: java, java-web-start, signing

I am having an issue with WebStart. I am a coder for an Indy game company, and we are trying to do an admin-only test on the site. I signed the working code, threw it onto the server, made a JNLP and started it. It doesn't work.

It is supposed to be a launcher, and get the runtime. Then when the user clicks Start Game, it runs the command `java -jar` on the run time.

Now, since we are an indy company and just starting out, we can't afford a professional certificate yet, so I had to enter all my info in Java's KeySigner. Now, here is the weird part. The **signed code can't** do `java -jar`, even if its ran from the desktop. The **unsigned code, however, can** do `java -jar`... And I can't do unsigned code for WebStart.

So, what do I do??? Is this a bug, and is there anything I can do to fix it without a professional certificate? Any help would be appreciated!

[EDIT] Here is the code in question http://pastebin.com/nDK8NZFE [EDIT]

Comment: What do you mean by `The signed code can't do java -jar`? You dont start it like that in WebStart. All you do is specify the class with a main method in the JNLP. Also could you post the error/exception thats being thrown?

Comment: I mean, it downloads the game launcher and starts it. When the user clicks start game, it makes a new file called F and that points to the game jar. The game jar is ran by Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); X is the location of the game, after you find the location of the jar...
          
      Process p = r.exec("java -jar " + x);

Comment: Error message please. I suspect this may be related to SecurityManager. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601088/can-a-signed-jar-be-run-as-an-executable

Comment: There are no errors, which is really what confuses me. The only time I can get the launcher to work is when it is unsigned.

Comment: Can you upload your JNLP for the launcher?

Comment: Try to get the output from your process.    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   for(String lineRead = reader.readLine();lineRead != null;lineRead = reader.readLine()) ... . Also open your signed jar and make sure your manifest has the right Main class in it.

Comment: If you cannot do java -jar on the signed code, you did something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps `java` isn't on the path. / I believe Comodo were doing code signing certs for US$100, and without the faff of much verification.

Comment: I made sure my PATH was set to my JRE install. Also, it works if its not signed, so I don't think it has to do with the path. Also, it fails if it is signed on other computers too. So, not just my machine.

Comment: Here is the code in question: http://pastebin.com/nDK8NZFE

Comment: @ajwgeek Why launch a new process at all? Cant you just run it from within the WebStart process?

Comment: The launcher has features, like settings, game updates, release notes, news feed, etc. We don't want to give that up ATM

Comment: @ajwgeek Thats not a problem look at Webservers. They dont run a new JVM for every webapp thats installed. They handle configuration and updates etc and then load the apps into the same JVM. Usually via its own ClassLoader. Its also easier to load balance the system that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, what I ended up doing was (Instead of being lazy this time) make a new render class that only renders the launcher stuff. So, now when you start the game, it asks for a username/password instead of doing it in a launcher. Then it is also the same process and I don't need two separate jars.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question. It is very unlikely, that a professional certificate would be any different. Actually i would be (somewhat) surprised if Java/WebStart could even tell the difference. I have been using self signed certificates for a couple years and never had any issues.

Check [Can a signed Jar be run as an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601088/can-a-signed-jar-be-run-as-an-executable) to see if this may be the issue.

You could also easily run the Game from the same JVM, which also gives you better control. (you could easily track stats for your Game inside the Launcher)

Comment: :( It didn't make a difference